# How to create a Google Form that creates a new folder per new response including all the files of that response (files may be marked as not required)

Tags: forms

I have the following script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1EDeROA7_4ZXNIoMtp973No0yAxRZDft_zURLuESHMFiEzs26kEiGNcd4TEXG37qNN159QAU3";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[10].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
  itemResponses[11].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
  itemResponses[18].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
  itemResponses[20].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

It was working but now I need to make some responses not required, can you advise me how to edit the script?

Thank you so much in advance!!

I tried that code but is not working because some responses are not required.